# Highcharts: Corner radius for plot border

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to provide a corner radius value for "plot border"?
Looking for something similar to the borderRadius option for the chart border. But we need it for the plot border.

I tried doing adding radius after loading the chart with the below but it does not work

```
chart.plotBorder.rx=5;
chart.plotBorder.ry=5;
chart.redraw();
```

Appreciate any help
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `element.attr()` method:

```js
  load: function() {
    this.plotBorder.attr({ rx: 10, ry: 10 })
  }
```

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tf53rd47/

However, as you can see, it won't work as it might be expected.

Comment: Nice trick! If you turn off grid lines, it looks a bit better. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/46/)

Comment: It works, as idea in this topic is about setting plotBorder radius, not series border radius for area type chart. In the fact all you can do (in SVG) is set for clippath `rx` and `ry` some values, but only using "#highcharts-2" id. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/3bQne/58/